# Nested if statement in for loop

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

So heres my script

```
function printPower

sum=0;
filename=input('Enter a filename: ','s');
power=load(filename);
for i=1:length(power);
    if power(i)>=0;    
        sum=sum+power(i);
    end
    TP=sum/24;
 end
 fprintf('Total power: %.1f kWh.\n', TP);
```

There are negative values in the text file im loading and I want it to only sum the positive ones but it still sums all values.

Answer (score 1):

You could just replace your loop with something like

```
total = sum(power(power>=0))/24
```

Personally I think that using the name of a Matlab intrinsic function, such as `sum`, as a variable name is just asking for trouble though I'm not sure it's caused a problem in your case.  That's why the lhs of my statement is the variable `total`.

Comment: Actually, the lhs should be named `TP` to be consistent with the question. Just sayin' :) (sorry for nitpicking...)

Comment: You're right @EitanT, but heck it's not my code, let OP figure that out for herself.